# One column with foreign key to multiple tables inf EntityFramework Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, domain-driven-design

Is it possible to model such relation in EF Core?

```
class EntityA
{
public EntityAId Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

```
class EntityB
{
public EntityBId Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

```
enum TableTypes {A,B}
```

```
class TransitionEntity
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string TransitionName {get;set;}
public TableTypes  TableType {get;set;}
public TableTypeId int {get;set;}
}
```

EntityAId and EntityBId are strongly typed entity identifiers.

The idea is when table containing TransitionEntity has:

- TransitionEntity.TableType = TableTypes.A then use relation TransitionEntity.TableTypeId  == EntityA.Id.Value
- when TransitionEntity.TableType = TableTypes.A then use relation TransitionEntity.TableTypeId  == EntityB.Id.Value

I'd like to have one-to-one relation. I tried to use TPH Hierarchy approach but no luck. Is it even possible in EF Core?

Comment: Why do you need it this way?  Why not just use int for your IDs?

Comment: There are many advantage of using strongly typed keys. One of them is easing switching key type (i.e from int to guid) without need to change it in every entity. You just simply change underlying type in strongly typed id.

Answer (score 0):

For all the others, I figured this out and it is possible. Using TPH is the key.

1. Create proper inheritance:

```
abstract class TransitionEntity
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string TransitionName {get;set;}
public TableTypes  TableType {get;set;}

}
```

```
class TransitionEntityA:TransitionEntity
{
public EntityAId EntityAId {get;set;}
}
```

```
class TransitionEntityB:TransitionEntity
{
public EntityBId EntityBId {get;set;}
}
```

2. Configure TransitionEntity fluent builder

```
        public void Configure(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder<TransitionEntity> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
            builder.Property(b => b.Id) 
//other props
builder.HasDiscriminator<TableTypes >("TableType")
    .HasValue<TransitionEntityA>(TableTypes.A)
    .HasValue<TransitionEntityN>(TableTypes.B)
```

3. Configure proper overrides using fluent api.

```
Configure(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder<TransitionEntityA> builder)
 {
     builder.Property(d => d.TableTypeId ).HasColumnName("TableTypeId");

 }
Configure(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder<TransitionEntityB> builder)
 {
     builder.Property(d => d.TableTypeId ).HasColumnName("TableTypeId");

 }
```

4. Configure EntityA and EntityB using fluent api.

```
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EntityA > builder)
  {
      builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
      builder.Property<EntityAId>("Id")
      .HasConversion(id => id.Value, value => new EntityAId(value))
//other props
//you can extend class to use navigation, then use it like this
builder.HasOne(b => b.TransitionEntityA)
    .WithOne(p => p.TransitionEntity)
    .HasForeignKey<TransitionEntityA>(p => p.EntityAId );
```

Configure EntityB in the same way as EntityA. This approach initialy did not work because I had different vales than TableType.A and TableType.B in actual column TableType in TransitionEntity table. So I think it is important to cover all existing values from column which serves as discriminator.

Hope it helps.